# Private Domains without SAP

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, sap

I have a question regarding Private Domains without SAP.

Sending Volume will be around 50K a month (too low for a dedicated IP), will use a shared IP.

Ignoring branding for images and links (which I know would come from SAP), Is it possible to add 2 sending domains as private domains without SAP?

Would multi-bounce still apply in this case?

Or would it be better to go for SAP with a shared IP, email.brand1.com and add a private domain, email.brand2.com and enable multi-bounce?

I think it's a limitation with SAP that brand2's images and links will be wrapped with brand1 due to that being the SAP domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will always recommend you to set up a Sender Authentication Package on your account, rather than having Private Domains only (and hence sending with generic Marketing Cloud domains). What will happen, as you also correctly write, you will have an SAP domain of email.brand1.com and add a private domain, email.brand2.com.

So in the past this was only safe if all domains involved were part of the same domain name - or if you did not implement DMARC on those domains. There is a newer feature called multi-bounce domain (which you also refer to). When that is enabled, the system will always change the bounce domain setting to be bounce.[from domain] - like this:

- From domain: **brand2.com**
- Bounce domain auto-set to: **bounce.brand2.com**

Hence you can use a PD different from your SAP domain. Multi bounce is enabled upon request, by submitting a support case requesting help setting up multi-bounce domain support for your new private domain.